# Filling with few 0s in an identity matrix using python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I want to fill an identity matrix with few 0s. I have `X,Y` coordinates `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]` and those coordinates should be 0s and others should be filled with 1.

This is for a shortest path problem. The algorithm  will output the shortest path  as coordinates

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

How can I do this in python?

Sample Input matrix `[4][4]`

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

Sample Output matrix `[4][4]`

```
0 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the indeces you have in your coordinates-array and assign the values of your array to be modified at those indeces to 0, like so:

```
for i in coordinatesArray:
    toModify[i[0]][i[1]] = 0
```

If your array to be modified isn't already filled with ones, add them first by using a for-loop:

```
for i in range(x):
    toModify.append(y * [1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the coordinates you want like for example:

```
for row, column in coordinates:
    ones[row][column] = 0
```

If you don't already have the matrix with ones you could maybe use a list comprehension so that you only have to iterate once (performance depends on the relation of ones to zeroes in that case)